# EXPRESS and SQL "syntax error at or near "$""

Tags: sql, express, psql

I'm making PFP route with EXPRESS and PSQL and I have a little problem.

I get an error

> Syntax error at or near "$"

Code:

```
if (!imgbbLink.startsWith("https://ibb.co/")) {
  return res.status(400).json("Something went wrong")
}

await pool.query(
  "UPDATE users SET user_profile_image = 1$ WHERE user_id = $2",
  [imgbbLink, req.user.id]
)

res.json("PFP updated successfully")
```

I think there shouldn't be any problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What package do you use to execute SQL queries?

Comment: PG (postgresql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just made typo when indicated `1$` instead of `$1`:

```sql
UPDATE users SET user_profile_image = $1 WHERE user_id = $2
```